# Subset sum - get array indices instead of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following function:

```
function createSubsets(numbers, target) {
  // filter out all items larger than target
  numbers = numbers.filter(function (value) {
    return value <= target;
  });

  // sort from largest to smallest
  numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  // array with all the subsets
  var result = [];

  while (numbers.length > 0) {
    var i;
    var sum = 0;
    var addedIndices = [];

    // go from the largest to the smallest number and
    // add as many of them as long as the sum isn't above target
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (sum + numbers[i] <= target) {
        sum += numbers[i];
        addedIndices.push(i);
      }
    }
    console.log(addedIndices);
    // remove the items we summed up from the numbers array, and store the items to result
    // since we're going to splice the numbers array several times we start with the largest index
    // and go to the smallest to not affect index position with splice.
    var subset = [];
    for (i = addedIndices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      subset.unshift(numbers[addedIndices[i]]);
      numbers.splice(addedIndices[i], 1);
    }
    result.push(subset);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This basically gets an array and it returns the subsets that sum up to `target`. Is it possible to change this function to return the subset indices (of the original `number` array) that sum up to target?

Comment: when you have values you may find indices for it. Using filter function at the beginning you create new array, so the found indices wound not match the original ones.

Comment: Can you not just do: subset.unshift(addedIndices[i]);

Comment: When you reach while loop numbers array is not the original array. It is sorted and filtered. Keep in mind that.